# Why does the Stack Exchange hot question widget resize?

Tags: discussion, design, hot-questions, android-app-widgets

When using the Stack Exchange hot question widget, I noticed one thing. When the text covers only two lines, the widget is smaller than when the text has three or more lines (more than three gets replaced with `...`). Why does it resize? Isn't it more logical to add a newline to the two line questions, so the size stays consistent?

[image: Two-line question]

[image: Three-line question]

Comment: Please forgive me for the giant images, I have no idea how to resize them.

Comment: So, it is better to hide the full title?

Comment: @Oded no, but I think adding a newline to shorter question titles would make the size stay the same.

Comment: Leaving blank space won't look good, in my humble opinion.